# Google Analytics Dashboard for WP in Custom Column

Tags: custom-post-types

So I've customised my custom post type columns so they display in the order I would like.

```
add_filter('manage_publications_posts_columns', 'set_publication_custom_columns');
function set_publication_custom_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns = array(
    'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'title' => __('Title'),
    'pub_category' => __('Categories'),
    'pub_tag' => __('Tags'),
    'thumb' => __('Cover'),
    'date' =>  __('Date'),
    'analytics' => __( 'Analytics' )
   );
  return $columns;
}
```

But I'm using the Google Analytics Dashboard for WP plugin which adds an 'Analytics' column and stats icon at the end. Except now I've customised my columns I don't know how to call the GADWP to appear or use in my

```
add_action('manage_publications_posts_custom_column', 'custom_publications_columns', 10, 2 );
function custom_publications_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
...
}
```

?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp

Comment: You can look at that plugin's code to learn how it is done, or ask its developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Searched in the `google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp` plugin folder for `posts_custom_column` and found reference to **gadwp_stats**:
`'gadwp_stats' => __( 'Analytics' )`